# I am completely new to Redux, I am trying to make a post request with axios but I am getting 422 Unprocessable content error or GET_ERRORS in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

Here is the code, I have the object as it is in the backend but I don't understand what's unprocessable content. I want to know If I am doing the redux part right and I can't see the POST_DEPARTMENT in the redux dev tools so the api request is not a success I believe

departmentAction.js

```
export const postDepartment = (request) => async(dispatch) =>{
      try{
const token = localStorage.getItem('bearer_token');
      const res = await api.post(`v2/science/departments/`, request, {
        headers:{
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
        }
      }).then((res) =>{
        console.log('response')
        dispatch({
          type: POST_DEPARTMENT,
          payload: ''
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err))
      });
}catch{
dispatch({
          type: GET_ERRORS,
          payload: res.data
        })
}
      
  }
```

CreateDepartment.js

```
const callApi = (formObj) => {
    dispatch(postDepartment(formObj));
 }
```

departmenttypes.js

```
export const POST_DEPARTMENT = "POST_DEPARTMENT";
```

Comment: Check what you're sending in the browser's devtools and compare it to what is expected. We can't see what's inside `request` any why your backend responds like that.

Comment: Thank you for replying, yeah just found out it was the format of the content.